# Generalized version of multiplicity of roots in the derivative.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that for complex polynomials, $p \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, if $p$ has root $\alpha$ with multiplicity $m$, then $p'$, the formal derivative, has root $\alpha$ with multiplicity $m-1$. For what types of polynomial rings $R[x]$ is this rule true for (R = fields, UFDs, etc.)?

Comment: It’s true for $R$ any integral domain.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez oops, yes. Good old $x^p$ in characteristic $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not anything deep going on and if one writes the proof, it is clear what conditions must hold. Let $p(x)\in R[x]$ have a root $\alpha\in R$ of multiplicity $n$. Then $p(x)=(x-\alpha)^n q(x)$. Differentiate this to get $p'(x)=n(x-\alpha)^{n-1}q(x)+(x-\alpha)^nq'(x)$. Then, provided that $n(x-\alpha)^{n-1}q(x)$ is not zero, you get the claim.

So it's true for any integral domain and any $n$. Or, it is true provided the characteristic of the ring does not divide $n$.